# Photon unity - игроки не видят друг друга

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я разрабатываю онлайн-игру в Unity, используя Photon. У меня проблема с игроками. Один игрок видит другого, а другой не видит первого. В консоли ошибка: `Received OnSerialization for view ID 1001. We have no such PhotonView! Ignore this if you're joining or leaving a room. State: Joined`

Я пробовал перенастраивать компоненты фотон на игроке, но это не дало никаких результатов. Пожалуйста помогите

Вот часть кода, которая отвечает за спавн игрока

```
if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "1Level")
{       
    Vector3 randPosition = Spawns[Random.Range(0, Spawns.Length)].transform.localPosition;  
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    SpaswnedPlayer = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Player.name, randPosition, Quaternion.identity);
ScoreBoardplayers.Add(SpaswnedPlayer.GetComponent<PlayerManager>());
}
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` в Unity делать нельзя, совсем. Для ожидания есть корутины.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую